# Using Router DOM with React.js TypeError: Cannot read property "name" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-dom

I am trying to implement the React Router on my React.js application but as soon as I added the Router to my program I started getting a weird error.

```
    ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    <Route path="/" component={Headline}></Route>
    <Route path="/economy" component={Economics}></Route>
  </BrowserRouter>,
```

This is where I am implementing my **`<Router>`** component in index.js. But for some reason as soon as I add this to my application, I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

name is the parameter of one of my objects, userInput, that I am passing via props to my child component, "headline" from App.js

```
<Headline
          userInput={this.state.userInput}
          money={this.state.money}
          displayFakeNews={this.state.displayFakeNews}
          onPublish={this.handlePublish}
        />
```

Inside the headline.jsx file, I am calling a **`<button>`** tag with the text rendering `{this.props.userInput.name}` and it the error comes up.

**As soon as I remove the `<Router>` component from the index.js file, everything starts working absolutely perfectly.**

*Note - Yes I tried to put the `<Router>` component in my App.js as well. And no I did not forget to import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes, you're declaring that the component to be rendered at route "/" is the `Headline` component, but you're not passing it any props. This means that whenever you visit the home page, the `Headline` component is likely trying to access unassigned properties.

From your question, I assume that you already have the `Headline` component being rendered in your `<App />` component, and in this file, it is actually being passed the necessary props. If its already being rendered there, you don't need to use the `<Route />` outside of the `<App />`. It's not clear the functionality you're looking for or how you've written your `<App />` component, but I think what you should keep in mind is that the syntax you're using doesn't pass any props to `<Headline />` from the route. If you actually want to pass those props, change

```
<Route path="/" component={Headline}></Route>
```

to

```
<Route path="/">
  <Headline
    userInput={this.state.userInput}
    money={this.state.money}
    displayFakeNews={this.state.displayFakeNews}
    onPublish={this.handlePublish}
  />
</Route>
```

Passing the component to be rendered as a child of the route, so that you can actually pass it props.

Consult the [React Router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) for more information on how to use the `<Route />` component.